# Bag storage before international flight from LAX

Tags: luggage, lax, los-angeles

Next week I'll be returning a rental car near LAX and waiting for a night flight with Air New Zealand. I expect to be returning the car by 2pm at the latest but checking for my flight doesn't even open until 6pm. I'd like to be free to go around the city and shop, particularly Glendale mall 26 miles away. I want to return the car with as little city driving as possible. I don't fancy lugging my suitcase across town or through a mall so is there some where I can store a bag for a few hours?

Comment: Why not turn the car in later, drive to the mall, and get to LAX around 6? Getting to the mall will be much much easier as a side benefit.

Comment: @Jon, because the cars all have the steering wheel on the wrong side and getting across town while dodging on coming traffic doesn't appeal.

Comment: How are you intending to get to Glendale Mall without a car? Taxi? Uber? Public transport? Where is your hotel? Any chance you could leave your luggage there and pick it up on the way to LAX?

Comment: @jcaron I'll be staying in San Diego the night before and would ask for advice on taxis/public transport  etc later

Comment: @Craig For future reference, it might have made more sense to get an open-jaw plane ticket. I'm assuming you flew into LAX but flying home-LAX and then San Diego-home on an open-jaw return doesn't usually cost much more than flying home-LAX-home, and would have saved a bunch of hassle. Also, your 52-mile detour to the mall is the equivalent of driving half-way back to San Diego, but each to their own.

Comment: You might ask for public transport advice *now*, because it all interlocks, and is likely to be the critical path.  L.A. public transit is a famous contradiction in terms, *and they're earnestly trying*. Also, the "we are returning a rental car, yet we cannot drive in L.A. because of wrong side steering" narrative doesn't make sense.  How about stopping at Fashion Island Mall Newport Beach instead of Glendale? It's enroute from S.D...

Comment: And it’s not like the Glendale mall isn’t right off I5 as well. Yeah, freeway driving is easier than surface streets, but still seems an interesting boundary condition is being applied.

Comment: @JonCuster Glendale, and particularly the area around the Galleria, [probably isn't a good place](https://losangeles.cbslocal.com/2018/09/05/glendale-los-angeles-worst-drivers-report/) for someone even slightly uncomfortable with with U.S. roads/cars in general... it can be intense.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle - understood, although one could say that about most of California. If one is ok driving from San Diego to LAX, it isn’t that much of a stretch to find a suitable mall on the way.

Comment: Glendale was of particular interest due to the Lego store. But it seems easier to go to Legoland on the way so I'm probably just going to drop the car on time and go straight to LAX. Some of the conditions on this trip are to do with who is paying for what. It's a work trip and my side visit to San Diego doesn't factor into the company booking me a flight in and out of LA.